# Is it possible to write Impala UDAF using existing class implementation

Tags: c++, hadoop, impala

I have a C++ implementation of a class for aggregate calculation on a list of items. I need to do the same calculation on a dataset stored in Hadoop using impala. I was planning to write an UDAF to do the calculation. Is it possible to use the existing class implementation to write update and merge functions?

I have seen few examples in here : https://github.com/cloudera/impala-udf-samples/blob/master/uda-sample.cc. However, none of the examples use an object to store intermediate results.